# Autosource files on change

Tags: r, module

What I like about `python` modules, is that after importing some function from it, the behaviour of this function during runtime can be changed by just applying the changes to the module file.

Suppose for example I have `test.py` module with the following function defined in it:

```
def fun():
    return 5
```

Now in IPython console I import and execute this function

```
> from test import fun
> fun()
5
```

Now I go to `test.py` and change the function definition (and save changes):

```
def fun():
    return 10
```

Executing `fun()` in console now results in:

```
 > fun()
 10
```

I think this is a [IPython specific feature](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html). This makes writing and testing code more efficient. In `R`, to get similar behavior, I have to source the definition file manually on each change.

Any way how to get similar behavior in `R`?

PS I know RStudio supports "Source on Save" (which is fine), but limited. It doesn't allow me to source into specific environments (which I usually do to keep the global environment clean).

Comment: I don't think it is possible, must source after every change.

Answer (score 0):

One workflow in RStudio that is similar is to use R packages (which correspond roughly to Python modules).  After you complete the changes you want to use, click on `Install and Restart`, and the changes are saved and the package is rebuilt and reloaded.

This also automatically saves your changes in their own namespace (the package namespace).

Comment: If you're using packages, you can just quickly load with cntrl + shift + L, keeping you environment.